# Listing items can't be deleted at first click?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just fetched data from Database and displayed all the data in table format.But when I try to delete a item then it can't be delete at the first click and right after that the second time I click it is deleted.

Here is the delete :

```
<td><a href="?id=<?php echo $table_data['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
```

And here is the delete query:

```
$del_id=$_GET['id'];

if($del_id){
$delete_data=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE from police_station where id='$del_id' ");
}
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: You know that you need to refresh your page after clicking on the delete link in order to see the updated items, right?

Comment: Thanks Buddy.It's working. I didn't set a header:location.so it didn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you are making this change asynchronously and the not updating the page or if you are simply not refreshing the page after the query is made.

Also another thing to keep in mind is that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should sanitize your input prior to inserting it into a raw query. You may also consider PHP's PDO.

Comment: You're right but it should be mentioned as a comment and not as an answer.